# Dexie promise in web worker never resolves/rejects

Tags: indexeddb, web-worker, dexie

**[SOLVED: See update at bottom]**

I am experiencing a weird problem with Dexie in web workers. I can't tell if the problem is being caused by Dexie, is a problem with IndexedDB, or has something to do with the way I'm using Dexie.

Here's a scenario that works fine:

- App starts up, sends request to server over websocket.
- Server responds with data over websocket; data is sent to web workers, that run various functions, run Dexie queries, update Dexie dbs, etc., then send data back to the main UI thread via `postMessage`.

Here's another slightly different scenario that works fine:

- While app is running, user interacts (e.g., clicks something), resulting in a request being sent to the server over websocket.
- Server responds with data over websocket; data is sent to web workers, that run various functions, run Dexie queries, update Dexie dbs, etc., then send data back to the main UI thread via `postMessage`.

Here's a scenario that doesn't work:

- While app is running, user interacts (e.g., clicks something), resulting in data being sent directly to a web worker. The web worker begins to run a Dexie query, but the very first promise it encounters hangs, neither resolving nor rejecting. Nothing happens and the app is stuck.

In other words, everything works fine as long as there is a round-trip to the server, but a direct **UI thread -> web worker thread -> Dexie call** doesn't work.

The problem also occurs when instead of a Dexie call I try to access IndexedDB directly:

```
  try {
    const req = self.indexedDB.open('dummyDb');
    console.log('request', req);  // this works; I can log the request object
    req.onblocked = (evt) => {
      console.error('blocked', evt);  // this is never called
    };
    req.onerror = (evt) => {
      console.error('error', evt);  // this is never called
    };
    req.onsuccess = (evt) => {
      console.log('success', evt, req.result);  // this is never called
    };
  } catch (e) {
    onerror(e);  // this is never called
  }
```

Thus, it's definitely IndexedDB that is hanging, but why? It's behaving like a deadlocked transaction, but I have removed all of the (explicit) transactions from the code, and it still happens. I don't use `Collection.each()`, and I don't know if there are any other Dexie functions that use implicit transactions.

I'm unable to reproduce the problem in a simple app that just has two web workers, one that writes to a db and another that reads from the same db. So I'm at a loss for how to proceed to diagnose the problem.

**UPDATE**

Well, this turned out to be a red herring. What actually happened is that the web worker was inadvertently terminated elsewhere in the code, but had not yet been GCed. Even in that zombie state, however, it was able to accept a message and do work. But as soon as it hit the first await, its thread would forever remain unscheduled.

This is not the first time that the lack of an `onclose` or `onterminate` event in web workers has caused me trouble.